# Error rendering page: Error: Failed to load script: /_next/static/chunks/pages/_error-2280fa386d040b66.js

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, next.js

[here is a picture of static directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yABXt.png)
This website runs properly locally but then when I deployed it to heroku, it would load halfway and then go blank, the chrome console pops up errors I haven't still been able to find solutions to (It was built using next.js, django and postgresql). I'm new to all of this, please I need help?

favourndubuisi.herokuapp.com

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to configure static directories in your Django setup as Django is trying to process the `_next` directories.

See the error reported on one of the missing chunks.

http://favourndubuisi.herokuapp.com/_next/static/chunks/821.ff7693b6a698a8d3.js

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://favourndubuisi.herokuapp.com/_next/static/chunks/821.ff7693b6a698a8d3.js
Using the URLconf defined in config.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
about/
projects/
technologies/
contact/
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, _next/static/chunks/821.ff7693b6a698a8d3.js, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

However, this chunk works
http://favourndubuisi.herokuapp.com/static/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-77a9eb1106a2340d.js

which means you have a static directory, I would place all items under `static` from `_next` under your Django `static` directory including the chunks folder.

Comment: Please I'm having trouble understanding your answer, where I should copy the items from and paste the items to?

Comment: Take the output of _next/static directory after prod build , all items and place them under your http://favourndubuisi.herokuapp.com/static/ directory. In a successful production build you will find the chunks under static.

Comment: Hi, I did transfer all files from inside static\_next\static directory to inside static directory but it still didn't work.. I attached a pic of my static directory to my question for possible reference

Comment: The path should be `static/_next/static/chunks` your screenshot shows `static/chunks`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by deleting and recreating the static files